In Flutter project When I add image_picker and run ./android>./gredlew build I'm getting errors
To reproduce my probbem

create sample flutter project
flutter create Test
in the project folder
cd android
./gradlew build --stacktrace
Ok
Add in pubscpec.yaml image_picker: ^1.1.2
Run again
cd android
./gradlew build --stacktrace

--Error

Task :image_picker_android:testDebugUnitTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':image_picker_android:testDebugUnitTest'.


There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/github/access/store44/build/image_picker_android/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest/index.html

Multiple version of image_picker
